# Receiving (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) and (Net::ReadTimeout) when starting CLI Application After ChromeDriver Update

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, nokogiri, watir

I am trying to refactor some code in a CLI scraper application. This application scrapes a site using Nokogiri and Watir gems. When I tried to run it, I needed to update the webdriver as I was now using a new Chrome version. After updating to the newest Chrome version I am now getting the following error in my terminal Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
Traceback (most recent call last):. I have confirmed that it is connecting to the desired site but then times out. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I have tried removing and reinstalling, chromedriver. I have also updated Capybara, checked the website that I am trying to scrape to ensure that it is up, and cleared the cache.

Comment: ReadTimeout means it can't access the page you're telling it to go to. Connection refused on chromedriver means that the driver was stopped for some reason. You can take a look at what all errors are getting raised by setting `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug`.

Comment: Does this code get added to the Selenium Webdriver logger file?

Comment: By default it is sent to stdout, you can specify a file location with `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = 'selenium.log'`